# update a post meta from a single table cell TablePress

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, metabox, post-meta, table

I have the following scenario
I have a lot of tables created by TablePress. one column in them is called Size which displays the size of some files in bytes. tablepress have a summing function called "sum" I will use it in the last row to sum all of the data in that column, I want to make that data saved as a post meta so I can sum it later
any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is quite tricky and difficult, cause table press math evaluation class has some protected method.

By the by I solved your issue.

Just the code in the functions.php in the theme.. just copy and paste it should be work. You can use multiple row sum.

```
require_once TABLEPRESS_ABSPATH . 'classes/class-tablepress.php';
$formula_evaluator = TablePress::load_class( 'TablePress_Evaluate', 'class-evaluate.php', 'classes' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_link_check_click_counter', 'link_check_click_counter');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_link_check_click_counter', 'link_check_click_counter' );

function link_check_click_counter() {

  $table_name = $_POST['old_data']['tablepress']['name'];
  $table_id = $_POST['old_data']['tablepress']['id'];
  $table_description = $_POST['old_data']['tablepress']['description'];
  $table_data = $_POST['old_data']['tablepress']['data'];
  $allResults = json_decode(stripslashes($table_data));
  $table_meta = $table_name ."_". $table_id;

  $neval = new TablePress_NEvaluate();
  $data = $neval->evaluate_table_data( $allResults );
  foreach($data as $value){
    update_option( 'table_press' . $table_meta, $value );
    update_option( 'table_press' . $table_id, $table_id );
  }
  die();
}

add_action('admin_footer' , 'table_press_custom_meta_add',0);
function table_press_custom_meta_add(){

   ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   //
   jQuery( '.wp-admin .save-changes-button' ).on( 'click',function() {
      var data =  { action: 'link_check_click_counter', old_data: tp.table.prepare_ajax_request( 'tablepress_save_table', '#nonce-edit-table' )  };
      jQuery.ajax({
        'type': 'POST',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'url': ajaxurl,
        // 'data': tp.table.prepare_ajax_request( 'tablepress_save_table', '#nonce-edit-table' ),
        'data': data,
       success: function(data) {
          console.log('test');
       }

      } );

   });

   </script>
<?php
}

class TablePress_NEvaluate {

  /**
   * Instance of the EvalMath class.
   *
   * @since 1.0.0
   * @var EvalMath
   */
  public $evalmath;

  /**
   * Table data in which formulas shall be evaluated.
   *
   * @since 1.5.0
   * @var array
   */
  public $table_data;

  /**
   * Storage for cell ranges that have been replaced in formulas.
   *
   * @since 1.0.0
   * @var array
   */
  public $known_ranges = array();

  /**
   * Initialize the Formula Evaluation class, include the EvalMath class.
   *
   * @since 1.0.0
   */
  public function __construct() {
    $this->evalmath = TablePress::load_class( 'EvalMath', 'evalmath.class.php', 'libraries' );
    // Don't raise PHP warnings.
    $this->evalmath->suppress_errors = true;
  }

  /**
   * Evaluate formulas in the passed table.
   *
   * @since 1.0.0
   *
   * @param array $table_data Table data in which formulas shall be evaluated.
   * @return array Table data with evaluated formulas.
   */
  public function evaluate_table_data( array $table_data ) {
    $this->table_data = $table_data;
    $rows = count( $this->table_data );
    $columns = count( $this->table_data[0] );

    // Use two for-loops instead of foreach here to be sure to always work on the "live" table data and not some in-memory copy.
    $i = 0;
    $data = array();
    for ( $row_idx = 0; $row_idx < $rows; $row_idx++ ) {
      for ( $col_idx = 0; $col_idx < $columns; $col_idx++ ) {
        $test = $this->_evaluate_cell( $this->table_data[ $row_idx ][ $col_idx ] );
        //print_r($test);
          if (strpos($test, 'Sum') !== false) {
            $data[] = $test;
          }

        $this->table_data[ $row_idx ][ $col_idx ] = $this->_evaluate_cell( $this->table_data[ $row_idx ][ $col_idx ] );
      }
    }

    return $data;
  }

  /**
   * Parse and evaluate the content of a cell.
   *
   * @since 1.0.0
   *
   * @param string $content Content of a cell.
   * @param array  $parents Optional. List of cells that depend on this cell (to prevent circle references).
   * @return string Result of the parsing/evaluation.
   */
  public function _evaluate_cell( $content, array $parents = array() ) {
    if ( '' === $content || '=' === $content || '=' !== $content[0] ) {
      return $content;
    }

    // Cut off the leading =.
    $content = substr( $content, 1 );

    // Support putting formulas in strings, like =Total: {A3+A4}.
    $expressions = array();
    if ( preg_match_all( '#{(.+?)}#', $content, $expressions, PREG_SET_ORDER ) ) {
      $formula_in_string = true;
    } else {
      $formula_in_string = false;
      // Fill array so that it has the same structure as if it came from preg_match_all().
      $expressions[] = array( $content, $content );
    }

    foreach ( $expressions as $expression ) {
      $orig_expression = $expression[0];
      $expression = $expression[1];

      $replaced_references = $replaced_ranges = array();

      // Remove all whitespace characters.
      $expression = str_replace( array( "\n", "\r", "\t", ' ' ), '', $expression );

      // Expand cell ranges (like A3:A6) to a list of single cells (like A3,A4,A5,A6).
      if ( preg_match_all( '#([A-Z]+)([0-9]+):([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)#', $expression, $referenced_cell_ranges, PREG_SET_ORDER ) ) {
        foreach ( $referenced_cell_ranges as $cell_range ) {
          if ( in_array( $cell_range[0], $replaced_ranges, true ) ) {
            continue;
          }

          $replaced_ranges[] = $cell_range[0];

          if ( isset( $this->known_ranges[ $cell_range[0] ] ) ) {
            $expression = preg_replace( '#(?<![A-Z])' . preg_quote( $cell_range[0], '#' ) . '(?![0-9])#', $this->known_ranges[ $cell_range[0] ], $expression );
            continue;
          }

          // No -1 necessary for this transformation, as we don't actually access the table.
          $first_col = TablePress::letter_to_number( $cell_range[1] );
          $first_row = $cell_range[2];
          $last_col = TablePress::letter_to_number( $cell_range[3] );
          $last_row = $cell_range[4];

          $col_start = min( $first_col, $last_col );
          $col_end = max( $first_col, $last_col ) + 1; // +1 for loop below
          $row_start = min( $first_row, $last_row );
          $row_end = max( $first_row, $last_row ) + 1; // +1 for loop below

          $cell_list = array();
          for ( $col = $col_start; $col < $col_end; $col++ ) {
            for ( $row = $row_start; $row < $row_end; $row++ ) {
              $column = TablePress::number_to_letter( $col );
              $cell_list[] = "{$column}{$row}";
            }
          }
          $cell_list = implode( ',', $cell_list );

          $expression = preg_replace( '#(?<![A-Z])' . preg_quote( $cell_range[0], '#' ) . '(?![0-9])#', $cell_list, $expression );
          $this->known_ranges[ $cell_range[0] ] = $cell_list;
        }
      }

      // Parse and evaluate single cell references (like A3 or XY312), while prohibiting circle references.
      if ( preg_match_all( '#([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)#', $expression, $referenced_cells, PREG_SET_ORDER ) ) {
        foreach ( $referenced_cells as $cell_reference ) {
          if ( in_array( $cell_reference[0], $parents, true ) ) {
            return '!ERROR! Circle Reference';
          }

          if ( in_array( $cell_reference[0], $replaced_references, true ) ) {
            continue;
          }

          $replaced_references[] = $cell_reference[0];

          $ref_col = TablePress::letter_to_number( $cell_reference[1] ) - 1;
          $ref_row = $cell_reference[2] - 1;

          if ( ! isset( $this->table_data[ $ref_row ] ) || ! isset( $this->table_data[ $ref_row ][ $ref_col ] ) ) {
            return "!ERROR! Cell {$cell_reference[0]} does not exist";
          }

          $ref_parents = $parents;
          $ref_parents[] = $cell_reference[0];

          $result = $this->table_data[ $ref_row ][ $ref_col ] = $this->_evaluate_cell( $this->table_data[ $ref_row ][ $ref_col ], $ref_parents );
          // Bail if there was an error already.
          if ( false !== strpos( $result, '!ERROR!' ) ) {
            return $result;
          }
          // Remove all whitespace characters.
          $result = str_replace( array( "\n", "\r", "\t", ' ' ), '', $result );
          // Treat empty cells as 0.
          if ( '' === $result ) {
            $result = 0;
          }
          // Bail if the cell does not result in a number (meaning it was a number or expression before being evaluated).
          if ( ! is_numeric( $result ) ) {
            return "!ERROR! {$cell_reference[0]} does not contain a number or expression";
          }

          $expression = preg_replace( '#(?<![A-Z])' . $cell_reference[0] . '(?![0-9])#', $result, $expression );
        }
      }

      $result = $this->_evaluate_math_expression( $expression );
      // Support putting formulas in strings, like =Total: {A3+A4}.
      if ( $formula_in_string ) {
        $content = str_replace( $orig_expression, $result, $content );
      } else {
        $content = $result;
      }
    }

    return $content;
  }

  /**
   * Evaluate a math expression.
   *
   * @since 1.0.0
   *
   * @param string $expression without leading = sign.
   * @return string Result of the evaluation.
   */
  public function _evaluate_math_expression( $expression ) {
    // Straight up evaluation, without parsing of variable or function assignments (which is why we only need one instance of the object).

    $result = $this->evalmath->evaluate( $expression );
    if ( false === $result ) {
      return '!ERROR! ' . $this->evalmath->last_error;
    } else {
      return (string) $result;
    }
  }

}
```

I am updating the in value in the update_option table.It is better cause you to have specific table id.

```
get_option('table_press' .$table_id); // get the id so now you can use any where in the shortcode.

get_option('table_press' .$table_name ."_". $table_id); // get sum of table press specific name and id
```

i am also answer [your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/259210/update-custom-post-type-meta-from-a-shortcode) from here. I will brief you how use this in that question.