# update custom post type meta from a shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, metabox, post-meta, table

I have the following scenario: I have a custom post type called "tablepress_tables" that is create by the plugin "Wordpress",
Tablepress has a shortcode to display the number of rows which is 
`[table-info id=123 field=number_rows /]` This will give rows number let's say 45
my question is I want to update every 'tablepress_tables" with a meta containing the number of rows that this post have, so the shortcode "id" will need to be changed automatically 
any idea on how to do that? or where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you will pull [the code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/259198/update-a-post-meta-from-a-single-table-cell-tablepress/259252#259252) from here.

Now you have table id

```
get_option('table_press' .$table_name ."_". $table_id);
```

so you can chage shortcode id dynamiclly using do_shortcode().

Comment: that will add the table_press id that is embedded in the post? what if the post have multiple tables? like 5?